# Java: Test class independent of second class

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have two classes: Class A and Class B. Class A requires instance of Class B, so that it can utilize certain methods from Class B. Now, I want to test Class A independently of Class B using JUnit. Alternatively, if Class A needs an instance of Class B in its constructor, how can I test Class A independently of Class B with JUnit?

I initially tested it depending on Class B, but that approach proved to be incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried Mockito to mock Class B ?

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly the purpose of a Framework like [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito). All you have to do is to add Mockito to your classpath. If you are using Maven, simply add the dependency. If you are using JUnit 5, your pom.xml will look like this :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Your test class might then look like this :

```java
class classATest{
    @Mock
    private ClassB classB;

    private ClassA classA;

    //This method is used to create an instance of the class under Test
    //If you're using a FrameWork like SpringBoot, your might not need this.
    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp(){
        this.classA = new ClassA();
    }

    @Test
    void simpleTest(){
        //Given : Here you configure your mock object classB
        when(classB.someMethod()).thenReturn(someStaticValue);
        //When : Call the method to be tested on classA
        classA.callSomeOtherMethod();
        //then : Check the results
        assertEquals(expected,actual);
    }

}
```